# when to use t-test or z-test when computing p-value

Tags: statistics

Here are two seperate question

Q1) An observed sample of four observations from a $N(u, \sigma^2)$ distribution has mean $62.75$ and standard deviation $4.57$. Assess the hypothesis $H_0 : u = 66$ by computing the relevant p-value

Which you just use the formula to get the p value $2\left[1 - \Phi(\frac{\bar{x} - u_0}{sd/\sqrt{n}}) \right]$

in this case $\Phi$ is a t distribution

Q2) Suppose measurements (in centimeters) are taken using an instrument. There
is error in the measuring process and a measurement is assumed to be distributed
$N(µ, σ^2)$, where µ is the exact measurement and $σ_0^2
= 0.5.$ If the (n = 10) measurements $4.7, 5.5, 4.4, 3.3, 4.6, 5.3, 5.2, 4.8, 5.7, 5.3$ were obtained, assess the hypothesis
$H_0 : µ = 5$ by computing the relevant P-value.

This is the same thing as above except we use $z$ distribution for $\Phi$. Why?

Comment: For each problem, apply both tests and compare the resulting $p$-values. You should find they're much more different in Q1 than Q2, because the $z$ option is only an approximation to $t$, and this approximation improves with increasing sample size.

Comment: But what signal is there that I should use $z$ over $t$ or vice versa ?

Comment: In theory one would always use $t$, but in practice this is only feasible for small $n$, since the CDF becomes harder to precisely compute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some confusion here. Perhaps printouts from software will help
you get oriented.

**1) Use t test--with sample standard deviation from data:** In Minitab, the *two-sided* t test (alternative $H_a:\mu \ne 66)$ 
results in the following output:

```
One-Sample T 

Test of μ = 66 vs ≠ 66

N   Mean  StDev  SE Mean      95% CI          T      P
4  62.75   4.57     2.29  (55.48, 70.02)  -1.42  0.250
```

Because the P_value exceeds 5%, you cannot reject $H_0.$
I am not sure how you are supposed to find the P-value in this case. Using a normal approximation is inappropriate because
the sample size is so small. By looking at the row for DF = 3 in
a printed t table, you can see that the test is not significant
at the 5% level. You would have to use statistical software (or a statistical calculator) to find the exact P-value.

Using R statistical software (in which `pt` represents the CDF
if a t distribution), I get the same value shown by Minitab.

```
2*pt(-1.42, 3)
[1] 0.2506892
```

In the graph below, the P-value is the sum of the two areas
outside the vertical red lines.

[image]

You are correct that you would use a t distribution (specifically with 3 degrees of freedom). However the symbol $\Phi$ is reserved for the *standard normal* CDF, so your notation is incorrect. [Also, your formula would not work even if you used the CDF of $\mathsf{T}(3).$]

**2) Use z test--population variance is known:** I get $\bar X = 4.88$ for your $n = 10$ observations. *Because
the population variance is known* to be  $0.5,$ you will use a z statistic
to test $H_0: \mu = 5$ against $H_a: \mu \ne 5.$ Here in Minitab output:

```
One-Sample Z 

Test of μ = 5 vs ≠ 5
The assumed standard deviation = 0.707

 N   Mean  SE Mean      95% CI          Z      P
10  4.880    0.224  (4.442, 5.318)  -0.54  0.591
```

Once you have the *exact* $Z$-statistic (-0.5367, display rounded to `-0.54` in Minitab output), you can use normal tables to evaluate the P-value $\approx$ 0.591 with good accuracy.  Again here, you cannot reject.

```
z = (4.880-5)/sqrt(.5/10);  z
[1] -0.5366563
2*pnorm(z)
[1] 0.591505
```

You should use formulas in your text to verify the key quantities
in the Minitab output for both tests.